# JavaFX - Trying to update my Textfield from another class

Tags: java, xml, javafx, fxml

So I have this shopping basket application that I made with JavaFX. What I am trying to do is when I clear the shopping basket to start from fresh I can clear my table view as I can trust set the table data to nothing but I am struggling with clearing my Text fields as I do not know how to access them.

Here is my TextFields in my BasketOverviewController

```
    @FXML
    public TextField noItemsField;

    @FXML
    public TextField totalField;
```

And  here is the two methods to update the textfields.

```
public void getTotalItems() {
        int total = 0;
        ArrayList<Items> itemList = new ArrayList<>(MainApp.itemData);
        for (Items item : itemList) {
                total += item.getQuantity();
        }
        noItemsField.setText(total + "");

}

    public void getTotalPrice() {
            double total = 0;
            ArrayList<Items> itemList = new ArrayList<>(MainApp.itemData);
            for (Items item : itemList) {
                    total += item.getTotal();
            }
            totalField.setText("£" + df.format(total));
            // returns the total of each item through for loop
    }
```

So say if I click new or open a new XML document within  my shopping basket these two textfields do not update unless I do another action when these two methods are called and then the BasketOverviewController is then called. I am wondering if there is anything that I can do in the RootLayoutController to call them or set them to 0 when it set to 0. Here is the code in my RootLayoutController to create new or open the XML documents.

RootLayoutController

```
@FXML
private void handleNew() {
    mainApp.getItemData().clear();
    mainApp.setItemFilePath(null);
}

@FXML
private void handleOpen() {
    FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();

    // Set extension filter
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extFilter = new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter(
            "XML files (*.xml)", "*.xml");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(extFilter);

    // Show save file dialog
    File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(mainApp.getPrimaryStage());

    if (file != null) {
        mainApp.loadItemDataFromFile(file);
    }
}
```

So basically I have a BasketOverviewController which contains the textFields that I need to change when a new XML document is made as this is what the file type the shopping basket creates and when I open an XML document I need the Total text field to update and the No.Items to update. Now I have tried creating a reference to my BasketOverView controller and tried editing the textfields that way but I am always getting a NullPointerException.

[Here you can see the shopping basket that I have made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ty3E.png)

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question with only partial information. Please check out how to post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question.

Comment: Sorry! Let me update it to so I explain it better.